# Single sign-on support for REST APIs

Tags: rest, oauth, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

I am trying to find the best way to solve the following problem: our application is SaaS, and it supports SAML for web login. The application also exposes REST APIs that are supposed to be used in automated and unattended processes, meaning there is no interactive user to type credentials. We need to allow developers to programmatically authenticate the unattended process against the relevant IdP (which is already defined, because the same credentials used for API access can also be used to access the web application).

The flow I imagine is as follows: the program authenticates using a dedicated API, gets a token and uses the token for the next calls.

Most of the answers I find when searching for best ways to secure REST APIs suggest oAuth, which normally requires an interactive user, because they discuss an interactive application tryign to access REST APIs in other system on behalf of the user, who is there to type in the password. Is oAuth the answer for my challenge as well? If so, what is the flow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed OAuth 2.0 can be used for this use case because it allows so-called *clients* (i.e. your unattended processes) to obtain an access token granted by developers and use that token against your APIs.

A typical flow to use here is the *code* flow: you would run an Authorization Server that issues tokens to clients if consented to by developers. Developers would login to the Authorization Server using SAML Web SSO.

Note that it does not require an active user at the time of accessing the REST API, but it would require one at the time of token issuance. I believe that is what you are actually looking for. If not, there are other flows that can be leveraged that don't require an active user at all, but I believe they are not suitable for this particular use case; after all you want the clients to operate on behalf of the developers.

Your Authorization Server may also issue a *refresh token* to the client in addition to an *access token* so that upon expiry of the old access token, your client can get a new access token from the Authorization Server using the refresh token, without having to (interactively) involve the developer again.

Comment: Hans, actually, I am looking for a completely unattended flow. Meaning, the developer is a user with credentials to access the web login, and I want him to be able to programatically use the same credentials to get the token and use it to access the API. So the token issuance is an unattended process as well. Does it make sense? What should be the flow? In particular, if an authorization server is involved in the flow, is it supposed to be on my side (as a service provider) or in the identity provider side? does it make sense for the SP side to know the password?

Comment: mmm... but perhaps the last section in your answer is what I am looking for.

Comment: yes, you need to bootstrap with the developer credentials at the IDP but you can't use them directly at the SP since that would defeat the purpose of using SAML

Comment: If you have the certificate infrastructure in place for SAML then you could just use PKI client auth.

Comment: Here is my problem - I need the client that invokes the API to be simple, hence it cannot handle exchanging refresh tokens for access tokens. I see there is also an option to use Resource Owner Credentials grant - do you think it is a good direction?

Comment: not really, also in response to the PKI comment: your should leave authentication up to the Identity Provider and not make any assumptions about its implementation (e.g. PKI or username/password); but your mileage may vary depending on your relationship with the IDP: the Resource Owner Password Credentials grant would require the developer to type his **IDP** username/password in to **your** client which defeats the purpose of SAML and inherently locks down the way of authentication to username/passwords (e.g. no way to upgrade to multi-factor and/or PKI)

Comment: A related question - suppose I use oAuth 2.0 and user X is authenticated and gets a access token and a refresh token. Now the user is deleted in the IdP and should have no access to the API. But the token is still valid, and even when using the refresh token, the user is not validated again against the IdP. So the deleted user has API access. What are my options here?

Comment: for that scenario you'd use something like [SCIM](http://www.simplecloud.info/) to synchronize account provisioning/deprovisioning between SP and IDP